# If $ \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = A $ and $ \lim_{x \to +\infty}f'(x) = B $, prove that $B = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

Problem: Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a function of class $ C^1 $ such that $ \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = A $ and $ \lim_{x \to +\infty}f'(x) = B $ for $ A, B \in \mathbb{R} $. Prove that $B = 0$.

I need help in validating my proof. Here it goes: 
Suppose that $ B \neq 0 $. Take $ \epsilon = B+1 $. From the definition of limit to infinity, the following holds: $ (\exists M > 0)(\forall x > M) | f'(x) - B | < B+1 $ 
From there, $ 1 < f'(x) < 2B + 1 $ (for all x greater than M). 
Now, take an interval $ [M+1, M+2] $. $ f $ is continuous on that segment, so it's bounded and reaches it's maximum and minimum. Function $ f $ is also differentiable on that segment, and if we apply [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)#Statement) (on local maximum/minimum), we'll get a contradiction, since $ f'(x) > 0 $ for all $ x \in [M+1, M+2] $. Therefore $ B = 0 $.

Comment: $B+1$ might not be positive

Comment: You don't use $B\neq 0$, why can you take $\varepsilon=B+1$ ? nothing ensures you that $\varepsilon>0$. From $|f'(x)-B|<B+1$ you get $-1<f'(x)<2B+1$, this is not what you wrote.

Comment: My apologies, can I take $ \epsilon = B $ if $ B > 0 $, and $ \epsilon = -B $ if $ B < 0 $? I think that solves my issue?

Comment: If you do that, you get that $|f'(x)|>0$ for $x\geqslant M$ which is good but not sufficient since you could still have $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=A$ (take $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is :

By the definition of the limit, there exists $M>0$ such that $|f'(x)-B|<\frac{|B|}{2}$ for $x\geqslant M$. We suppose without loss of generality that $B>0$ (otherwise consider $-f$), then for $x\geqslant M$, we have $f'(x)>B-\frac{|B|}{2}=\frac{B}{2}$. Thus, for $x\geqslant M$,
$$ f(x)=f(M)+\int_M^xf'(t)dt\geqslant f(M)+(x-M)\frac{B}{2} $$
Taking the limit as $x\rightarrow +\infty$ gives that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$.

Comment: Is there a way that integrals could be avoided? I have only covered continuity and differentiability so far from real analysis.

Comment: To avoid integrals, show that $g(x) = f(x) - f(M) + (x-M)B/2$ is strictly positive for $x > M$ by showing that $g(M) = 0$ and $g'(x) > 0$. (Rolle's theorem will help.)

Comment: *$g(M)=0$ (I agree).

Comment: @Tuvasbien: thanks. I've fixed my comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed several mistake here.

First, $B+1$ might not be positive, thus you cannot set $\epsilon = B+1$ and assume that it is a positive number.

Second, $|f'(x) - B| < B+1$ does not imply $1< f'(x)$. Instead you have

$$  -B-1 < f'(x) - B < B+1 \Leftrightarrow -1 < f'(x) < 2B+1.$$

In particular, you do not have $f'(x) \neq 0$.

Third, in the closed and bounded interval $[M+1, M+2]$, maximum/minimum might be attained at the endpoints $M+1, M+2$, so Fermat's theorem might not be applicable (note that in wikipedia, Fermat's theorem is applied to functions defined on open interval $(a, b)$).

Comment: This is the best answer so far. It explains very clearly all the issues in the asker's approach. I wonder why no votes so far. +1

Answer (score 0):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that $B\neq0$. Choose
$X_{1}>0$ such that $|f'(x)|>\frac{1}{2}|B|>0$ for all $x\geq X_{1}$.
Since $f(x)\rightarrow A\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $M>0$ and $X_{2}>0$
such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\geq X_{2}$. Let $X_{3}=\max(X_{1},X_{2})$.
Choose $x_{1},x_{2}\in[X_{3},\infty)$ such that $x_{2}-x_{1}>\frac{4M}{|B|}$.
By mean-value theorem, there exists $\xi\in(x_{1},x_{2})$ such that
$f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})=f'(\eta)(x_{2}-x_{1})$. On one hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
|f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})| & = & |f'(\eta)(x_{2}-x_{1})|\\
 & > & \frac{1}{2}|B|(x_{2}-x_{1})\\
 & > & 2M.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
|f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})| & \leq & |f(x_{1})|+|f(x_{2})|\\
 & \leq & 2M.
\end{eqnarray*}
We arrive a contradiction!